# Edit the previous search string in emacs query-replace?

Tags: emacs

When using query-replace (with or without regexp) in emacs, the previous query-replace pair is remembered and suggested as default the next time query-replace is invoked. But I would like to be able to edit this default replacement to something similar without having to type the entire new variant.

Like this:

in a section of a long document I do a query-replace

```
M-% antidisestablishmentarianism-A [return] antidisestablismentarianism-B
```

later on in the same document I want to do

```
M-% antidisestablishmentarianism-A [return] antidisestablismentarianism-C
```

The command M-% on its own gives

```
Query-replace (default antidisestablishmentarianism-A -> antidisestablismentarianism-B):
```

Is there some magic key combination which makes it possible to change that final "B" to a "C" without retyping?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yah, try <kbd>M-p</kbd>, something like this sequence

```
M-% M-p [return] M-p [DEL] C [return]
```

Comment: Thank you! M-p was indeed the magic button I did not know about. Experiment and emacswiki confirm that M-p gives the previous command in the minibuffer history - so by varying the number of "M-p"'s it is possible to edit the query, replacement string or both.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @Alice Lesser's useful comment: M-p brings back the minibuffer history for past invocations of the specific command you're executing. It can be any of a number of commands, not just query-replace. So using it with ido-find-file brings back only strings that were used with ido-find-file, etc. Even more magic!

Answer (score 2):

I can also use C-r.  It shows me all the entries in minibuffer and I can select from that.  I have C-r binded to M-x anything-minibuffer-history.  After M-x query-replace, hit C-h b and search for major-mode in the *Help* buffer.  That will give full list of command.  Here is my bindings.

```
C-g     abort-recursive-edit
TAB     self-insert-command
C-j     exit-minibuffer
RET     exit-minibuffer
C-r     anything-minibuffer-history
ESC     Prefix Command
C-tab       file-cache-minibuffer-complete
down        next-history-element
next        next-history-element
prior       previous-history-element
up      previous-history-element
M-n     next-history-element
M-p     previous-history-element
M-r     previous-matching-history-element
M-s     next-matching-history-element
```